# How to plot x==2.5(vertical line) with sympy

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I need to plot set of equations:

```
x1 + 2 * x2 == 8
x1 + 2 * x2 == 10
x1 == 5.5
x2 == 2.5
```

I am trying to use sympy for this:

```
from sympy import *
x1, x2 = symbols('x1 x2')
plot(
    solve(Eq(x1 + 2 * x2, 8), x1)[0], # x1 + 2*x2 <= 8
    solve(Eq(x1 + 2 * x2, 10), x1)[0], # x1 + 2*x2 <= 10
    5.5, # x1 <= 5.5
    Eq(x2, 2.5), # x2 <= 2.5 !<< This does not work as expected
    (x2, -2, 10)
)
```

Result is:

[image: plot of three equations]

It was quite easy for first three, but now I need to plot x2 == 2.5(vertical line where x2 == 2.5) and cannot get an idea how to do this.

May be sympy is not best solution here? Any other ideas for python?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `plot_implicit`.

```py
>>> from sympy import Symbol, Eq, plot_implicit
>>> x2 = Symbol('x2')
>>> plot_implicit(Eq(x2, 2.5))
```

[image: Plot]